# DotNetTor Cannot Make Requests

Tags: c#, .net, http, httprequest, tor

Recently I want to get a .json content from an onion site
(e.g. http://takedownmi4lfjhv.onion/root.json, this is an existing link)

So I installed the C# library DotNetTor ([Nuget package is here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetTor/))

I copy & pasted the [DotNetTor QuickStart Example Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1161078/QuickStart-TOR-in-NET-Core) sample code and ran it with my C# project.

```
        var requestUri = "http://icanhazip.com/";

        // 1. Get real IP
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var message = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
            var content = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Your real IP: \t\t{content}");
        }

        // 2. Get TOR IP
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new SocksPortHandler("127.0.0.1", socksPort: 9050)))
        {
            var message = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).Result; // GOT ERROR HERE // GOT ERROR HERE
            var content = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Your TOR IP: \t\t{content}");

            // 3. Change TOR IP
            var controlPortClient = new DotNetTor.ControlPort.Client("127.0.0.1", controlPort: 9051, password: "ILoveBitcoin21");
            controlPortClient.ChangeCircuitAsync().Wait();

            // 4. Get changed TOR IP
            message = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
            content = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Your other TOR IP: \t{content}");
        }
```

However, at the line I marked `// GOT ERROR HERE`, it poped up an error

```
System.AggregateException

Inner Exception 1:
TorException: Failed to send the request

Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9050
```

Why failed to send the request? How to resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is simply a Socks Proxy handler and **does not really contain anything about Tor**.

`new SocksPortHandler("127.0.0.1", socksPort: 9050)`

See this link of code. This is **nothing more than connecting via a SocksPortHandler 127.0.0.1:9050**

But this port is not yet configured to Tor at all.

So before this, you should configure the port.

You can download the Tor Expert Bundle from [here](https://www.torproject.org/download). This can help you configure that port for Tor.